# Copy element without content using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, copy, element

i´m desperately looking for a simple solution to my problem and hoping that someone out there is able to help :).

**Problem:**
Given is a xml document containing elements with attributes. I need to pick some element values, put those before the elements and remove the elements content afterwards using xslt. Here comes the tricky part. I need to do this only for elements which are **not** embedded in a certain other element such as `<a>`.

**Example:**

```
<document>
  <text>Some text <element attribute="123">"abc"</element> more text.</text>
  <text>Lots of text...</text>
    <a><element attribute="123">"abc"</element></a>
</document>
```

**Transform to:**

```
<document>
 <text>Some text "abc" (<element attribute="123"></element>) more text.</text>
 <text>Lots of text...</text>
   <a><element attribute="123">"abc"</element></a>
</document>
```

**My solution so far:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element[not(ancestor::a)]">
    <xsl:value-of select= "." />
    <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select= "." />
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will generate the following:

```
<document>
  <text>Some text "abc" (<element attribute="123">"abc"</element>) more text.</text>
  <text>Lots of text...</text>
     <a><element attribute="123">"abc"</element></a>
</document>
```

This is quite close, but not the wanted result. Now I need to remove the "abc" from the first element or even copy the element without its content, but I´m not able to and somehow stuck to my solution. Anyone here who is able to enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `<xsl:copy-of select= "." />` you want

```
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
```

which does a shallow copy and copies the attributes.